# How can I add new window to my project in using quickly?

Tags: python, quickly, glade

I'm new to glade and python. But the code generated by *quickly* when making my first app is so much confused for me to understand.

I don't know where should I add the code to initialized my new window, I think connecting it to button should be easy.

Comment: As this is a developer question, you may want to re-post this in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

The command is `quickly add dialog dialogname` and needs ran from the app directory. Note, the word "Dialog" is automatically added to the dialog name.

Answer (score 0):

The command to create a new dialog using quickly is **quickly create dialog dialog name**, where dialog-name is the name of the dialog you want to create. This command should be run from within your quickly app directory. This will create a new .ui file in Glade when you relaunch it, and a new Python file will be opened the next time you run **quickly edit**. Consult the Quickly Tutorial by running **quickly tutorial** from within your app directory for more information on adding dialogs. I have not noticed any difference between adding a dialog with the Quickly command and manually creating a dialog in Glade and adding the necessary code to a Python file, but please correct me if you (or anyone) know otherwise.

Comment: Aaron Thanks for your replay but I still facing problems with creating new windows...
I did as you suggest and when I run this command **quickly create dialog dialog-name** within my app directory I get **You can't launch /usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/create.py command within a project. Please choose another path.
Aborting**